# How to connect to PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS from Excel VBA via SSH tunnel?

Tags: vba, postgresql, ssh, amazon-rds, adodb

Here's the VBA code that I'm using to connect to a local instance of PostgreSQL:

```vb
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "DSN=PostgreSQL-Local"
```

This is what the ODBC data source setup looks like:

[image]

Now, I want to connect to the prod version in Amazon RDS, which is not publicly available. I've set up the SSH tunnel (via an EC2 instance) and I'm able to connect to the database after configuring DBeaver's SSH tunnel tab.

[image]

So, I know that the SSH tunnel works perfectly well.

I tried:

- finding configuration options in the ODBC data sources
- searching the internet for connection strings

However, I'm stuck with figuring out how to do it using VBA's `ADODB` connection.

Answer (score 0):

The opensource psqlODBC driver doesn't come with integrated ssh tunneling.

DevArt sells a driver which does, or you can install your own tunneling software and set up the tunnel yourself.  In the latter case, you would need to then point your ODBC driver at localhost:5433 (or whatever port you chose to use locally--I gave that as an example as 5432 seems to already be in use locally)